# Trailing space to UITableViewCell issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIView` (height of 1 and constraints leading space to the superview and trailing space to the super view) on a `UITableViewCell` which acts like a custom line separator.

The issue right now is that when I add an `accessoryView` to a `UITableViewCell` the trailing space doesn't extend to the trailing space of the superview, but instead stops at the accessoryView. I kind of understand why this happens, but I am trying to see how I can get around this.

[image: The UIView line has a trailing space to the superview]

Comment: Are you saying you add an accessoryView to the custom uitableviewcell seperator?

Comment: I add an accessoryView to the custon UITabelViewCell, which has a custom UIView separator

Comment: No I see both the accessory view and the seperator

Answer (score 0):

You can add the separator view to the cell itself, not its `contentView`. `contentView` becomes smaller/moves when accessory view is added, or when actions are presented, while the cell itself stays the way it is.

Doing this is not prohibited, although documentation advises to add custom views to `contentView`, so keep an eye on further iOS updates.

Upd: you might need to `bringToFront` to make sure the separator is displayed above the content view (which is white by default).

Comment: in a storyboard a view cant be added to a cell. but, programmatically I think it works. and if its added by code It doesnt need to be brought to front

Comment: additionally, if this is added by code. you need to check if this is a reused cell or not. to prevent adding that seperator view more than once.

Comment: Of course @hasan83 is right you need to do that too. 
I'm not aware what level of experience the author has, some things are obvious. He asked how to make it go all the way wide and my answer covers that.